# how to fix `Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` error in android?

Tags: android, import, fragment

I am getting the following error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

for the following line

```
FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit()
```

I have the following imports in my class

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`, and make sure your class is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: I tried but I am getting an error to create that method. My class is an extends Activity class

Comment: Your class should extend `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: If my class extends Fragment and i am using a FragmentPagerAdapter then what should i do?

Comment: @ManishSB I'm stuck at same problem. Did you fix this??